# IE stops While recording in Loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I am new to loadrunner,i have installed loadrunner 11 in my machine,But when i start recording in Vuser my IE 8 stops responding .But i can open the wen page manualy.
Can anybody Help

Comment: What OS are you using? Which protocol(s) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your problem is still up to date.

You can try to start VUGen with the run as command (right click) and enter the credentials your webpage requires.

This might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

90% of issues of this type can be solved by looking at your system and credentials and matching those up to the requirements for the tool in question.   Also, if you have an aggressive antivirus installed this could be impacting the recording mechanism in an antagonistic fashion, so you may need to disable the antivirus solution for recording purposes.

As you note that you are new, have your core foundation skills been confirmed, have you been through training and are your working with a mentor?   If the answer to all three is "no" then you will probably want to run for the trees because at some point your management is going to toss you under a bus to salvage a client relationhip.   This is not an "if," but a "when" whenever this combination of factors comes into play.